# Play - How to tell that an instance variable in model should not be mapped to a db column?

Tags: model-view-controller, playframework

Say I have a model class `User` with instance variable `password`. However, I only want to save `passwordHash` into database, and the instance variable will only serve as an intermediate value that I use to temporarily hold the original password so I can bcrypt it. How do I tell Play framework that I do not want to save `password` variable into db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add "@Transient" annotation on password:

```java
@Entity
public class User extends Model {
    @Transient         
    public String password;

    public String passwordHash;
}
```

[How to handle the "calculated" fields in a Play Framework model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933359/how-to-handle-the-calculated-fields-in-)
a-play-framework-model